# Vim Shell Command Confusion

Tags: shell, vim

I'm running gVim under Win 7.   I have this alias to compile my LESS file

```
cnoremap less  !lessc % > %<.css
```

Works fine.  But when I try to put a write command in front of it

```
 cnoremap less w<CR> !lessc % > %<.css
```

it puts this command string

```
.!essc % > %<.css
```

on the command line.  If I try the command sequence directly by putting

```
:w<CR> !lessc % > %<.css
```

on the command line, it seems to send the correct command to cmd.exe but tells me it can't open the .css file for writing (even if there isn't one already present.

I've tried concatenating the commands with the | operator but that worked even worse.

Totaly confused here.  Would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: `:cnoremap less w\|!lessc % > %<.css`

Answer (score 1):

If you

```
:set aw
```

([`:help 'autowrite'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'autowrite')) then you don't need the `:w` before `:!`.

```
:cnoremap less w \| !lessc % > %<.css
```

should work too.